# How to combine asp and php in one domain

Tags: web, development-environment

is that possible if we combine asp.net and php in one domain.
let say that domain is http://www.maindomain.com develop using php and hosted in linux server.

Our goal is http://www.maindomain.com/anotherpage this another page is develop in asp.net and host in different server and os

if this possible how to do it